# HTTP TOOLKIT - Can HTTP TOOLKIT intercept ALL network of the whole computer like Fiddler?

Tags: http-toolkit

I've seen a lot of videos from HTTP TOOLKIT and how to capture the traffic from specific Apps and Devices like Chrome or an Android Device. I wonder however, if I can also capture my whole Mac Computers traffic with it or if it always must be a specific app to intercept.

If I could use it to see all my Mac computers traffic, it would be a good & free alternative to Fiddler I guess.

I've searched for a feature like this within the HTTP TOOLKIT docs but I didn't find it mentioning such a feature.
So my question is: Is it possible to capture all network traffic on a Mac computer with HTTP TOOLKIT?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it to intercept all traffic from your computer. The only difference is that unlike other built-in options (for browsers like Chrome/Firefox/etc, for Android, for Docker, and so on) it's not totally automatic.

To do this, you just need to manually configure your system to use HTTP Toolkit as your HTTP proxy, and to trust the CA certificate that HTTP Toolkit has generated on your machine. The values you'll need for this are shown in the 'Anything' option on the Intercept page within HTTP Toolkit.

Once that's done, all traffic from your system should immediately start appearing in HTTP Toolkit.

Remember to disable the system proxy setting when you're done though! If you leave the proxy enabled, and quit HTTP Toolkit, then your internet connection won't work (because your system will keep try to send all network traffic to HTTP Toolkit, which won't work when it's not running).

Comment: That's planned, but there's no specific date yet. You can add a  to vote for issues to prioritize in the GitHub tracker here: https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Areactions-%2B1-desc